# Ambiguous functional form in kdb

Tags: kdb

not exactly sure what the following bit of code does:

```
p1:(,').(::;p@)@\:distinct#[;x]cols key p;
```

especially this part -> `(,').(::;p@)@\:`

from my understanding, takes the distinct columns table p is keyed by from x, but this bit `(,').(::;p@)` confuses me. Does that take the last value ? for each of the keyed columns ?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly what's happening because you aren't giving us the full context, but `::` is the identity function which just returns the same input, aka

```
q)(::)`a
`a
q)(::)1 2
1 2
```

and `p@` would be an index/lookup into keyed table `p`. So `(::;p@)` is a list of two functions - the first function being identity and the second being lookup into keyed table. The input `distinct#[;x]cols key p` is applied to each of the two functions `@\:` (apply-each-left). The first function output will be the distinct rows in `x` for the given keys of `p`. The second function output will be the lookup of those keys into the keyed table `p`.

Finally, `(,').` is the function `(,')`, aka append-each, dot-applied to both function results, see https://code.kx.com/q/ref/apply/#apply-index
This would be equivalent to

```
{x,'y}[functionResult1;functionResult2]
```

so in this example append-each for two tables is a sideways table join, see the bottom of https://code.kx.com/q/ref/join/